# jquery class selector issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have following buttons in my table

```
<td><Button  id="approval_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit"  class="myclass btn success trr" ><span>Approve</span> </button>
</td>
<td><Button  id="approval_<?php // echo $i; ?>" type="submit"  class="smyclass btn failed trr" ><span>Deny</span> </button>
</td>
```

I need to make a onclick action

some thing like this

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {}
```

problem is that how do I tell which button was clicked?

Comment: Give them some attribute you can reference. `id="button1"` and then in the click function `this.id`

Comment: Inside the click event handler `this` will refer to the button that was clicked. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: This will not validate your code. You cannot have a `span` inside a `button`. Check for your self: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the click function, you can reference the element the action was performed on by using $(this).

So:

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    $(this).doStuff();
});
```

Quick note - you're going to want to cache $(this). This way, you can reference it as many times as you want, but will only perform the DOM lookup once.

As in:

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.doStuff();
    $this.doMoreStuff();
});
```

Comment: If a function is only triggered on a click action, there is probably no need to cache $(this).

Comment: Doesn't matter where the function was triggered. If you reference a jQuery object more than once, the best practice is to cache it in a local variable. $(this) does a DOM lookup like everything else

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the button contains a class with the jQuery function [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('success')){
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

The keyword *this* will be the button you clicked. You can wrap it with jQuery by writing $(this), which will allow you to use a whole lot of handy jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    // In here "this" refers to your element that was clicked.
    // You can do whatever you want with it from here.
    // If you want to use jQuery make sure to wrap it like $(this)
});
```

I would suggest taking a look at the [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) it will explain a lot about how jQuery works which will save you alot of time in the future

Answer (score 0):

This way you will be able to get the index and define if it was "success" or "failed" that was clicked

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {
    // Get the index
    var index = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];

    // Check success or failed
    if ($(this).hasClass('success')) {
        // success
    } else {
        // failed
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I foresee a problem with this bit:

`id="approval_<?php echo $i; ?>"`

It occurs twice, once for each button. You do not want elements sharing an id for (among others) this reason. Change your code in the second button to something like:

`id="denial_<?php echo $i; ?>"`

Then inside of your `click` event handler, you can check against id for your behavior:

```
$('.myclass').click(function() {

    var action = this.id.split('_')[0];
    var identifier = this.id.split('_')[1];

    if (action == 'approval') {

        if (identifier == 'abc123') {

            alert('Why is the rum gone!?');

        } else if (identifier == 'def456') {

            alert('I have bath salts, wanna party?');

        }

    } else if (action == 'denial') {

        alert('Fact: Picture messaging is for lovers!');

    }

});
```